# Differentiate between Frontend and Backend Logs in DBTarget Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

1. I am logging into Db using existing Yii logging API.
2. But I want to differentiate between Frontend logs and Backend logs inside DB.
3. Everything that appears is common for both, I face difficulty tracing frontend logs.

Below is the image of DB Logs where GREEN marked are for backend logs, RED marked are for Frontend Logs.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Bizley!

Inside both **backend/config/main** and **frontend/config/main**, I configured below; This is how my entire log configuration for Frontend looks like(Similarly you can do it for Backend);

```
'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\DbTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error'],
                    'prefix' => function ($message) {
                        return "[Frontend]";
                    },
                ],
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error','info'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Below is the view on UI for logs. With the Help of Prefix I can now easily differentiate between channels.

[image]

Comment: Well, ok, glad to help. Since you unaccepted my answer and accepted yours maybe at least upvote?

Comment: I accepted my answer only and only because it gives a working example. I have mentioned credits for you first and then my answer, because it could not have been completed without your help. I really admire you for helping nature. I have upvoted your answer too. Thanks Bizley!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prefix` property for this. This is callable that returns a string to be prefixed to every exported message with signature `function ($message)`.

As default `getMessagePrefix()` is used there which prefixes the message with user IP, user ID and session ID.

You can use it to add there `frontend` and `backend`.

Comment: Ok ! I'll Check it and let you know

Comment: where and how to configure it?

Comment: This is Target class property so within configuration of your logs.